# Undefined variable in php script

Tags: php, android, mysql

Seriously , I have no idea what's wrong with my php script. I'm want to update data from android to MySQL through php script. **All the column value can be updated except `timein`**. I can't figure out what's wrong in my code.

[image]

**updateDetails.php**

```
<?php

    if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){
        //Getting values 
  $id =$_POST['id'];
  $project =$_POST['project'];
  $description =$_POST['description'];
  $progress =$_POST['percentage'];
  $timeIn =$_POST['timein'];
  $timeOut = $_POST['timeout']; 

   require_once('dbConnect.php');

 $sql = "UPDATE work_details SET  project = '$project', work_description = '$description', percentage = '$progress', timeIn = '$timein' , timeOut ='$timeOut' WHERE id = $id;";

  //Updating database table 
 if(mysqli_query($con,$sql)){
 echo ' Updated Successfully';
 }else{
 echo 'Could Not Update. Try Again';
 }
 //closing connection 
 mysqli_close($con);
    }

 ?>
```

**UpdateDetails function**

```
public void Update( final String project, final String description, final int progress, final String timeIn, final String timeOut)
{
    class UpdateInfo extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,String>{
        ProgressDialog loading;
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            loading = ProgressDialog.show(Edit_Details.this,"Updating...","Wait...",false,false);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            super.onPostExecute(s);
            loading.dismiss();
            Toast.makeText(Edit_Details.this,s,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
            HashMap<String,String> hashMap = new HashMap<>();
            hashMap.put(Config.KEY_ID,ID);
            hashMap.put(Config.KEY_PROJECT,project);
            hashMap.put(Config.KEY_DESCRIPTION,description);
            hashMap.put(Config.KEY_PROGRESS,String.valueOf(progress));
            hashMap.put(Config.KEY_TIME_IN,timeIn);
            hashMap.put(Config.KEY_TIME_OUT,timeOut);
            RequestHandler rh = new RequestHandler();
            String s = rh.sendPostRequest(Config.URL_UPDATEDETAILS,hashMap);

            return s;
        }
    }

    UpdateInfo ue = new UpdateInfo();
    ue.execute();
}
```

**Config**

```
  public static final String KEY_TIME_IN="timein";
```

Comment: you have define $timeIn variable but use $timein variable in your query, so you got this error.

Comment: ON updatedatail.php, after all variables (echo $timein;  exit();)

Comment: @GirishPatidar thanks..what a silly mistake...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your SQL statements has

```
"... timeIn = '$timein' ..."
```

But you declare the variable before that as

```
$timeIn =$_POST['timein'];
```

Make sure you fix your upper/lower case so that the variables match.

Comment: can you help ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34735076/undefined-index-image-in-php