# Undefined index image in php

Tags: php, android, mysql, image

Firstly,let me describe what are the issue I facing here.

I'm wanted to store the image path from `android` to `MySQL` and store the image into PhotoUpload directory.

When the submit button is clicked, all the `listItem` will be saved into `MySQL`.

**Activity A**

[image]

```
 public void uploadImageAndText(ArrayList<ImageAndText> listItems, final String id) {
            JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();
            try {
                for (ImageAndText i : listItems) {
                    JSONObject object = new JSONObject();
                    String type = i.getType();
                    String[] Type = type.split(":");
                    object.put("type", Type[1]);
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), Type[1], Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    String amount = i.getAmount();
                    String[] Amount = amount.split(":");
                    object.put("amount", Amount[1]);
                    String description = i.getDescription();
                    String[] Description = description.split(":");
                    object.put("description", Description[1]);
                    Bitmap uploadImage = i.getImage();
                    String image = getStringImage(uploadImage);
                    object.put("image", image);
                    object.put("ts_id", id);
                    jsonArray.put(object);
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            AddStaff ru = new AddStaff(jsonArray);
            ru.execute();

        }

        class AddStaff extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
            ProgressDialog loading;

            JSONArray jsonArray;

            AddStaff(JSONArray jsonArray) {
                this.jsonArray = jsonArray;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();
                loading = ProgressDialog.show(AddClaims.this, "Please Wait", null, true, true);
            }

            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
                HashMap<String, String> data = new HashMap<String, String>();
                data.put("listItems", jsonArray.toString());
                RequestHandler rh = new RequestHandler();
                String result = rh.sendPostRequest(Configs.STAFF_BENEFIT, data);
                return result;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
                super.onPostExecute(s);
                loading.dismiss();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), s, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }


        public String getStringImage(Bitmap bmp) {
            ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
            byte[] imageBytes = baos.toByteArray();
            String encodedImage = Base64.encodeToString(imageBytes, Base64.DEFAULT);
            return encodedImage;
        }
    }
```

**php**

```
<?php
    if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' ){

        if( !empty( $_POST['listItems'] ) ){

            $mysqli = new mysqli("127.0.0.1:3307", "root", "", "androiddb");
            if( $mysqli->connect_errno ) echo "Failed to connect to MySQL";

            $image = $_POST['image'];

            $listItems = json_decode( $_POST['listItems'], true ); 

            $sql="SELECT id FROM staff_benefit ORDER BY id ASC";

            $id=0;

            $res=$mysqli->query( $sql );
            while( $rs=$res->fetch_object() ) $id=$rs->id;

            $path="$id.png";
            $actualpath="http://192.168.107.115:80/Android/CRUD/PhotoUpload/$path";

            $sql="INSERT INTO `staff_benefit` ( `type`, `amount`, `description`, `image`, `ts_id` ) VALUES ( ?, ?, ?, ?, ? )";
            $stmt=$mysqli->prepare( $sql );

            $pathelements=array( realpath( $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] ), 'CRUD', 'PhotoUpload', '' );
            $savepath = realpath( implode( DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $pathelements ) ) . "{$id}.png";

            $bytes=file_put_contents( $savepath, base64_decode( $image ) );
            if( !$bytes ){
                echo 'Error saving image';  
            }

            if ( $stmt && $bytes ) {
                 foreach( $listItems as $item ){ 

                    $stmt->bind_param('sssss', $item['type'], $item['amount'], $item['description'], $actualpath, $item['ts_id'] );
                    $res=$stmt->execute();

                    if( !$res ) echo 'Query failed with code: '.$stmt->errno;
                } 
            }
            $mysqli->close();
        }
    }
?>
```

This is what I expected

[image]

**Error**

> Undefined index: image in C:...... Error saving images
>
> This is line 10    `$image = $_POST['image'];`

I know I'm getting this error message is because I only post `listItem` but no image. **My problem is how can I break the image in  listItem and then decode it ?**

Can someone please assist me on how to store arraylist(with image) into MySQL ?Thanks a lot

I'm follow this [tutorial](https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/android-upload-image-from-gallery-with-text/), but the problem is he storing a single file, not arrayList!

Comment: `$_POST['image']` => `$_FILES['image']`

Comment: To translate what Fred ii is saying:  uploads are in the $_FILES array, not in $_POST.

Comment: @Fred-ii- tried, no luck

Comment: @devlincarnate not really get it

Comment: you also need  valid enctype when dealing with files

Comment: @Fred-ii- all done in php ?

Comment: the PHP method is this way http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php - I don't remember how it's done in Android, you'll need to look that up.

Comment: @Fred-ii- but the problem is I store them into arraylist. I don't know how to break them into php, then decode it

Answer (score 0):

Since you get undefined in this  `$image = $_POST['image'];`, why you don't add `image` in your `doInBackground` ?

Try this

```
  @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
                HashMap<String, String> data = new HashMap<String, String>();
                data.put("listItems", jsonArray.toString());
                data.put(Configs.KEY_IMAGE,imagess);
                RequestHandler rh = new RequestHandler();
                String result = rh.sendPostRequest(Configs.STAFF_BENEFIT, data);
                return result;
            }
```